# Write multiple Data Frames in one Excel Sheet in R using XLConnect

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I have two different data frame with variable no of rows and columns.
For eg :-

```
exceldataframe <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 0), stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(exceldataframe) <- c( "Subject", "Session", "thermal data", "pp", "HR", "BR", "peda","performance(res)")
wb = loadWorkbook("MYDataSet.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "DataSheet")

statisticsFrame <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 5), stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(statisticsFrame) <- c("thermal data", "pp", "HR", "BR", "peda","performance(res)")
row.names(statisticsFrame) <- c("Valid", "Invalid", "Missing", "Not Applicable", "Sum")
```

I want to write exceldataframe first and then append after some rows the statisticsframe. Although statistics frame is getting appended but i want to leave spaces after first frame i.e excel data frame. Also I want to name the rows of excel while appending statistics data frame. Like rows should be named as Valid,Invalid etc.
I have written the following code :-

```
  writeWorksheet(wb, exceldataframe, sheet = "DataSheet", startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
  print(statisticsFrame)
  appendWorksheet(wb,statisticsFrame, sheet = "DataSheet", header = TRUE, rownames = TRUE)
  saveWorkbook(wb)
```

This appends the file but rownames are not being shown even after rownames = TRUE.Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I found out the solution..Before appending frame to worksheet..I did
statisticsFrame <- cbind(Values = rownames(statisticsFrame), statisticsFrame)..It works!.Thanks!